# Python: Data Validation using a Try and ValueError issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm writing a program which is a simple currency converter. I'm trying to validate the data so if you type in the wrong data type you are asked to type it again.

```
GBP_USD = 1.57
print('The current exchange rate is',GBP_USD)
change = input('Would you like to change this?(Y/N) ')
if change.lower() == 'y':
    GBP_USD = input('New Rate: ')
    while True:
        try:
            float(GBP_USD)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('That is not valid.')
            GBP_USD = input('New Rate: ')
            continue
while (change.lower() != 'y') or (change.lower() != 'n'):
    print('Please enter Y or N.')
    change = input('Would you like to change this?(Y/N) ')
    if change.lower() == 'y':
        GBP_USD = float(input('New Rate: '))
        break       
money = float(input('Money: '))
exchange = money * GBP_USD
rounded = ceil(exchange * 100) / 100.00
print('Dollars:',rounded)
```

This is what I get in the shell

```
The current exchange rate is 1.57
Would you like to change this?(Y/N) y
New Rate: three
That is not valid.
New Rate: 4
Please enter Y or N.
Would you like to change this?(Y/N) n
Please enter Y or N.
Would you like to change this?(Y/N) n
Please enter Y or N.
Would you like to change this?(Y/N) n
Please enter Y or N.
Would you like to change this?(Y/N) n
Please enter Y or N.
Would you like to change this?(Y/N) y
New Rate: 6
Money: 4
Dollars: 24.0
Would you like to quit?(Y/N)
```

Please help me I'm really confused :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing the wrong thing:

```
while (change.lower() != 'y') or (change.lower() != 'n'):
```

What if `change` is `'y'`? Then the first test is false, but the second is true. The same goes for `'n'`; the first test will be true, so the whole expression is true too. In fact, the expression is *always* true, no matter what you enter.

You want to use `and` here instead, **both** must be true for you to continue with the loop:

```
while (change.lower() != 'y') and (change.lower() != 'n'):
```

You could use a membership test instead:

```
while change.lower() not in 'ny':
```

You may want to study the canonical 'ask for input' question here on Stack Overflow for some more advice: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: Thank You very much for this. I did not realize that not in existed. After a quick google I now understand this and have applied it to some other areas of my code.